# how to update/install new package in the filesystem on embedded device?

Tags: linux, nginx, arm, lighttpd

I am a newbie to embedded world so please excuse me if this is a very beginner level question.

I am involved in a task where I need to update lighttpd on a device to support TLSv1.2. The device already has `lighttpd/1.4.31 (ssl) - a light and fast webserver`

OR

I am looking to replace lighttpd with NGINX since other system component already has it.

I am getting used to the embedded terms and looking for some kind of a guide to perform above tasks and introduce to more complex tasks.

Appreciate any helpful reference/articles/tutorials,

Thank you,

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. GoodLuck

Comment: From my limited exposure to embedded systems (i.e. Linux on a router/switch), you'll do better searching for forums that specficially support the tools/systems that you need to use (or for the hardware that runs your embedded system). Good luck.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/), [Internet of Things Stack Exchange](http://iot.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was looking for some starting guidance due to my knowledge in this area. We can update the software version via `make menuconfig` option. Below are some partial steps to perform,

Hope it will give some direction to newbie like me,

Look for `.config` file in your code-base, in my case it was inside `factory` directory.

```
$ svn co http://svn-path-to-factory-dir
$ cd factory
$ make menuconfig <--create .config if missing before this
$ select > Software Packages > Networking > HTTP Servers
$ deselect lighttpd
$ select nginx
$ enter inside nginx sub-fields and fill with appropriate entries, you can refer to other software-package in your build-environment for reference
$ Exit from all the menuoptions and save your configuration
$ do make
$ observe the build-environment is compiling your software package
```